# LabVIEW, C++ DLL, and IMAQ Images

Tags: c++, dll, labview

I'm familiar with writing DLLs that can be called from LabVIEW, but I'm curious as to what the correct way to pass IMAQ Images to a DLL might be.  Here's one way I've found to do it -- I also use a similar mechanism to post IMAQ Image instances from my DLL to an Event Structure.

[image: Example Diagram]

Note that the nodes that convert the image instances to/from clusters are located at `${LABVIEW_INSTALL_DIR}/vi.lib/vision/DatatypeConversion.llb`, and are named `IMAQ Image Datatype to Image Cluster.vi` and `IMAQ Image Cluster to Image Datatype.vi`, respectively.  The cluster that is created consists of the image name and an integer value that represents the pointer address to an `Image*` type in C/C++.

Is this the best way to do this, or is there a better way?

Comment: One problem I can see is that the conversion node is giving U32. If you're on 64 bit there may be problems...

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that -- that's happening because I'm defining the parameter for the function call into the DLL to be a `Pointer Sized Integer`.  Since I'm operating in a 32-bit environment, this doesn't affect me directly -- it is curious, though that a 32-bit output happens to be the case, as I am running NI Vision 2011, which purports itself to have 64-bit support.  Looking at the output from the cluster above, that does not seem to be entirely true...

Comment: OK, I'm pretty sure that in a 64bit environment it gives a 64bit pointer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use a different approach, putting all the image info (pointer, sizes, etc) in a cluster using the following code:

[image]

The cluster is then passed to the DLL function, making operations on pixels (no changing the size, of course) and afterward call IMAQ's unmap pixel pointer.

---

EDIT after discussion:

Your solution relies on having NI Vision, and in this case it's better than mine. However when not having NI Vision mine is the only way to work with IMAQ's pixel data.

Comment: That seems a little busy, especially considering that you can get access to all of that information from the `imageInfo` struct that is returned by reference in a call to `imaqGetImageInfo(_pImage, &imageInfo)`, where the address stored in `_pImage` is equivalent to the integer passed in the example in the question above.

Comment: didn't know this! what's the name of the noe before cluster's unbundle? anyway your solution seems better than mine, so you should go with it if it does the job :-)

Comment: Both the conversion nodes are located in `${LABVIEW_INSTALL_DIR}/vi.lib/vision/DatatypeConversion.llb`.  It's a pity that they aren't included on the IMAQ palette by default, honestly...

Comment: I don't have NI Vision that's why I didn't know about it